# Deleting duplicates from a single linked list

Tags: rust

```
pub fn delete_duplicates(head: Option<Box<ListNode>>) -> Option<Box<ListNode>> {
    let mut head = head;
    let mut cur = head.as_mut();
    while cur.is_some() && cur.as_ref().unwrap().next.is_some() {
        if cur.as_ref().unwrap().val == cur.as_ref().unwrap().next.as_ref().unwrap().val {
            //let next = cur.unwrap().next.as_mut().unwrap().next.take();  (1) Error!
            let next = cur.as_mut().unwrap().next.as_mut().unwrap().next.take();  // (2) Ok
            cur.as_mut().unwrap().next = next;
        }
        else {
            //cur = cur.as_ref().unwrap().next.as_mut();  (3) Error!
            cur = cur.unwrap().next.as_mut();  // (4) Ok
        }
    }
    head
}
```

The code above deletes duplicates inside a custom single linked list. (e.g. [1,1,2] -> [1,2])
Using (2) and (4) compiles and does what the program is supposed to do.
(1) and (3) generate compiler error and I just can't grasp what is happening here.

- (1) Why do we need `as_mut()`? I believe cur is already mutable.
- (3) Why can't I use `as_ref()` when assigning a value to lvalue?
- (4) Isn't this consuming the Options as we proceed?

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and paste the exact and entire error that you're getting — that will help us to understand what the problem is so we can help best. Sometimes trying to interpret an error message is tricky and it's actually a different part of the error message that's important. Please use the message from running the compiler directly, not the message produced by an IDE, which might be trying to interpret the error for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a reproducible [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2fda0bc1844901c733ffef8297401e04). Other folks, please use it to help and correct me if my answer is wrong.

For (1), when you call `cur.unwrap()`, the value (`Option<&mut Box<ListNode>>`) got moved from `cur`. but when you call `cur.as_mut()`, it gave you a `Option<&mut &mut Box<ListNode>>`, and unwrapping it doesn't move `cur`'s value. I created a small [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d163a6ba4b2011c37e02d15d216f52e6) code snippet to illustrate this.

For (3), it has two errors.

1. when you call `cur.as_ref()`, the value is behind a `&`, so you cannot access its value but then borrowed it as mutable again when you call `as_mut()`
2. if you replace the `as_ref()` call in (3) with a `as_mut()` call, you will see only the other error.

   ```
   Line 28, Char 17: cannot assign to `cur` because it is borrowed (solution.rs)
      |
   28 |                 cur = cur.as_mut().unwrap().next.as_mut();
      |                 ^^^^^^---^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      |                 |     |
      |                 |     borrow of `cur` occurs here
      |                 assignment to borrowed `cur` occurs here
      |                 borrow later used here
   error: aborting due to previous error
   ```

   You cannot first borrow `cur`'s value, reassign `cur` with a new value, then use the borrowed value. [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=93b613459557689ee8c4739c20691ef5) to illustrate this.

For (4), yes, it consumes `cur`'s value, which is a `Option<&mut Box<ListNode>>`, not `Option<Box<ListNode>>`, so it is OK.